# How to avoid saving document in Salesforce using DocuSign app launcher

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I am trying to implement a functionality where document should not be saved in Salesforce after filling and signing the DocuSign form.
It should be saved only in DocuSign account in DocuSign app launcher

Answer (score 0):

In DAL under the options tab, you should see "Document Writeback" unselect this for your template and it will not write back to your object